# Spring @Transactional does not rollback checked exceptions

Tags: mysql, transactions, spring-data

I have been stuck for a while to make Spring rollback a transaction when a checked exception is thrown using `@Transactional(rollbackFor)`. Here is my code:

The data access class:

```
@Repository
public class CustomerDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    public void willRollback() throws CheckedException {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(new SpringCustomer(null, "roll back"));
        throw new CheckedException();
    }
}
```

Where `CheckedException` is just a simple checked exception:

```
public class CheckedException extends Exception {}
```

The service class `CustomerService`:

```
@Service
public class CustomerService {
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomerDao customerDao;
    
    @Transactional(transactionManager = "hibernateTransactionManager", rollbackFor = CheckedException.class)
    public void willRollback() throws CheckedException {
        customerDao.willRollback();
    }
}
```

Beans configurations:

```
@Configuration
public class BasicConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_hibernate?useSSL=false");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("Passw0rd");

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.home.exception.checked");

        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory().getObject());
    }

}
```

And finally, here is my main class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = 
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Main.class); 
        
        try {
            ctx.getBean(CustomerService.class).willRollback();
        } catch (CheckedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

I've read many answers related to these questions, all of them suggesting to call the transactional method from outside the proxy itself, which I did. Regardless, the entity is always persisted in the database anyway and the transaction is not rolled back.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:** As per @kavithakaran-kanapathippillai answer, I debugged the `TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing()` method, and the following methods as well, and found that the rollback logic is executed. The entity still appears when querieng the db though.
So, I enabled db logging to see what queries are run, and I found the following:

```
2020-06-28T07:29:48.516038Z   391 Query SET autocommit=0
2020-06-28T07:29:48.520253Z   391 Query insert into spring_customer (name) values ('roll back')
2020-06-28T07:29:48.524969Z   391 Query rollback
2020-06-28T07:29:48.526026Z   391 Query SET autocommit=1
```

I don't know why this happens but it looks like the Spring rollback is working fine.

---

**UPDATE2:** The problem was due to my table was using the MyISAM engine (non-transactional engine). Once I changed it to InnoDB (a transactional engine), the record is not persisted anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The following method is where spring checks whether to rollback when an exception is thrown. Class name is `TransactionAspectSupport`. You can put a break point and see whether `txInfo.transactionAttribute.rollbackOn(ex)` is evaluating to `true`

```
protected void completeTransactionAfterThrowing(@Nullable TransactionInfo txInfo,
                                                Throwable ex) {
  if (txInfo != null && txInfo.getTransactionStatus() != null) {
     .....
    if (txInfo.transactionAttribute != null && 
        txInfo.transactionAttribute.rollbackOn(ex)) {
```

Reference:

[TransactionAspectSupport.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectSupport.java)

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I've updated the question with the new finding.

Comment: did you try the same sequence of operations directly in mysql? And if they don't roll back, may be worth raising a separate question with your table definition and keep the link here too

Comment: Thanks bro. The issue was due to using the MyISAM engine.